# magento customer sessions being mixed up

Tags: php, magento, session, cookies

I am facing session issues with Magento quite often. Customer sessions like login, cart being mixed up very badly.

1. Some users can login, Others cant. (With correct user id and password)
2. Some users see different user details when they login.
3. Cart is completely random. If a customer adds a product to cart, Others also getting same in their cart page. And randomly cart vanishes

I tried installing a fresh copy of Magento 1.9.1.1 CE. 
Problem is still there.

I tried below points as suggested in various forums so far with no luck

1. Added `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` in all the forms
2. Tried setting cookie domain as `.mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` and path as `/`
3. Tried disabling the cache
4. Tried modifying Varien.php as

```
$cookieParams = array(
'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
'path'     => $cookie->getPath()//,
//'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
//'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
//'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);
```

Session files are creating. I tried clearing server cache, cookie in my browser, session files, but still no luck.

Please help what exactly i am missing here. I haven't changed any other settings or files after fresh installation. Still problem persists.

Comment: _"I tried installing a fresh copy of Magento 1.9.1.1 CE. Problem is still there."_ have you tried to download a fresh copy? I'm not certain whether this is the issue but perhaps the first time you downloaded the package was / got corrupted?

Comment: Yes i tried it by downloading again. My installation went correctly. Even i tried installing earlier versions. This seems like a known issue when i went through some forums. But suggestions given over there is not working for me

Comment: Do you have external cache system like Varnish?

Comment: No i don't have any caching system. I just noticed that Varien session response is coming very late. This is one reason customer not logging in without any error. But if i refresh after few second I am logged in!